# Can you create a windows folder share using a local user group instead of a user to permit access?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, local-groups

Given I know how to set up a folder share on Windows 10 to allow [Everyone|Authenticated Users|specified users] access to a network share.

I recently tried to define share access using a local group, "Users". This is not the obsolete and useless "Homegroup" feature; in the permissions dialog, where you can add users, enter the name of a local user group and this will be accepted. The members of this group are local accounts, but linked to Microsoft logins, for password synchronization.

I found that users in this group were not able to access the share from a remote client, they would get an error message that their password is not right. In the host's event log I find an entry with ID 4625  (unknown user or bad password). This was tried through the file explorer as well as the `net` command. If tried on the host system itself from an account in the user group the attempt to access the share is successful though, the user can access the network path and also access files in it.

If I explicitly add the user's name to the share, remote access works for the share, too, but I would like to use groups here, as there will be multiple shares to be defined with different access levels to each group.

I am quite sure that in the past using local groups worked as expected, and somewhere with the latest Windows updates this feature was botched, probably when they introduced Microsoft live logins as default.

I had a chat with Microsoft second level support but that was little satisfying. All they were able to provide was a page on how to share folders with other users and no mention of groups.

If you have a similar setup functional, could you provide missing steps?

Comment: I've just tested that setup, on Windows 10 v1909 and v2004, everything works fine, the way it should work. What's the Substatus of error ID:4625?

Comment: Status:            0xC000006D,     Sub Status:        0xC000006A
have you tried with microsoft live id linked user?

Comment: Yes. But when I'm accessing my share I use LUser and not leshy@outlook.com(you have to do it that way). 0xC000006A means, user name is correct but the password is wrong. If you have local acc named LUser, when you login with LUser and connect your OUTLOOK acc with it, You are asked to change the password, password that you enter there will become the new password of your local user(LUser). So when you are accesing that share with LUser you have to use that new password.

Comment: When we use the local user name (it's `judit` for my daughter Judith) we came to the same results, before I wrote this question. But I might try it again.